# Get highest frequency of combination of two different values in a list in C#

Tags: c#, performance, linq, query-optimization

Preferably using System.linq

So in my program I have a list of Purchases which contain a list of Products. I am trying to determine which two products are more often purchased together in a single sale. For example:

Products - banana, apple, teddy bear, beer, diaper, video game, car

Purchases1 - banana, teddy bear, diaper, beer

Purchases2 - diaper, car, beer

Purchases3 - banana, video game, car

Most frequently bought together couple of products = diaper and beer.

Does anyone know the most optimal way of doing this? In practice my dictionary of Purchases has around 2.4 million elements in it and there 8013 unique products in the Products dictionary.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you have a List<Purchases> couldn't you group by the products and do a count?

Comment: If I group by products I will get the highest frequency of a single product, the problem is that I want specifically a combination of two distinct products. Since there are 8013 unique products, according to math there would be 8013!/2! combinations, right?

Comment: I believe it should be 8013!/((8013-2)!2!) = 32,100,078 Combinations of 8013 products taken 2 at a time.

Comment: Apparently the APriori algorithm is the best method. You know that if any single product item appears infrequently, then no pair containing that item can appear frequently, so you first you calculate the frequency of single items, then you exclude some reasonable number of those (e.g. singles are unlikely to be part of the most frequent pair). Can you show us your C# types?

Comment: Is it possible that a `Purchase` contains the same `Product` twice? If yes, then how this affects the counting of pairs? For example let's say that a purchase contains the 4 products "beer, beer, wine, wine". Does the beer+wine combination counts as one or two or four pairs?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create a `Dictionary` to keep track of your purchase pairs. Perhaps you could sort your purchase lists so that the entries are always in alphabetical order, then you can just iterate over the lists you have.

Below is a sample project I made that does what you are requesting, although the products are simply `char`. It may not be the most efficient, but it will at least show you a way to accomplish what you are asking.

```cs
    class Program
    {
        class Purchase{
            public List<char> Products = new List<char>();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            do
            {
                // here is our list of products
                char[] products = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' };

                // randomly populate a list of purchases
                Random random = new Random();
                List<Purchase> purchases = new List<Purchase>();

                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    var currPurchase = new Purchase();

                    foreach (var p in products)
                        if (random.Next(0, 2) > 0)
                            currPurchase.Products.Add(p);
                    purchases.Add(currPurchase);
                }


                // for all of our products, we need to make a dictionary of all the possible pairs
                Dictionary<(char, char), int> count = new Dictionary<(char, char), int>();

                // now for each purchase, we go through and see all the pairs that happened, and update those dictionary entries
                foreach (var purchase in purchases)
                {
                    // get the pairs, update the pairs
                    for (int i = 0; i < purchase.Products.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = i + 1; j < purchase.Products.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (count.ContainsKey((purchase.Products[i], purchase.Products[j])))
                                count[(purchase.Products[i], purchase.Products[j])]++;
                            else
                                count[(purchase.Products[i], purchase.Products[j])] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // then get the pair that had the highest frequency
                var highest = count.Max(kvp => kvp.Value);

                // and then get all the keys that occurred that many times (assuming we could have two pairs of equal frequency)
                var mostFrequent = count.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == highest).Select(x => x.Key);

                Console.WriteLine($"Most Frequent Pairs (Occurred {highest} times): ");
                foreach (var pair in mostFrequent)
                    Console.Write(pair + "; ");

                //type quit and hit enter to quit
            } while (Console.ReadLine() != "quit");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my attempt using LINQ:

```
var purchases = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string>() { "banana", "teddy bear", "beer", "diaper" },
    new List<string>() { "beer", "diaper", "car" },
    new List<string>() { "banana", "video game", "car" }
};

var itemsPairsOccurences = purchases
    // cross join every purchase with itself and produce items pairs, i.e.: correlate every item included in a purchase with every item from the same purchase
    .SelectMany(purchase1 => purchase1.SelectMany(_ => purchase1, (item1, item2) => Tuple.Create(item1, item2)))
    // filter out pairs containing the same items (e.g. banana-banana) and duplicate pairs (banana-car remains, car-banana is skipped)
    .Where(itemsPair => string.CompareOrdinal(itemsPair.Item1, itemsPair.Item2) < 0)
    // group all pairs from all purchases by unique pairs and count occurrences
    .GroupBy(itemsPair => itemsPair, (itemsPair, allItemsPairs) => KeyValuePair.Create(itemsPair, allItemsPairs.Count()));

// choose a pair with the most occurrences
var mostFrequent1 = itemsPairsOccurences.Aggregate((itemsPair1, itemsPair2) => itemsPair1.Value > itemsPair2.Value ? itemsPair1 : itemsPair2);
// OR order pairs by occurencces and select the first one
var mostFrequent2 = itemsPairsOccurences.OrderByDescending(itemsPair => itemsPair.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing all of this in RAM may turn out to be pretty resource intensive IMHO.

Although it may be premature optimization, I would go about this using the following logic:

- make a (distinct) list of all products (about 8,000 you mention)
- assign a prime-number to each product (according to https://primes.utm.edu/nthprime/index.php#nth the 8000th prime is 81,799 so we should not need to worry about overflows IMHO. (81,799 ^ 2 < int.MaxValue)
- for each purchase 'calculate' all the combinations by simply multiplying the corresponding prime number of each product. The benefit of multiplying here is that x.y == y.x and the resulting value is just an int too.
- add each result as a key in a dictionary<int, int>, when already there, value++
- in the end, sort the dictionary by its values (desc) and pick your top n
- factorize the keys again into the base primes to find the products involved

This should also work for combinations of 3, 4 etc.. products although you'll need to switch to longs or risk overflowing the integers.

I'm not sure if you can easily do this in LINQ, it's not really my cup of tea; in SQL it would be a breeze except for calculating the prime-numbers I guess... (although you can probably pre-calculate (or download) that into a static table, especially if you plan on running this more often).

PS: You can split up the Purchases list over n independent threads and merge the resulting dictionaries in the end; that might make it quite a bit faster if your hardware supports it.

Comment: Note that you can implement a simple pair -> list mapping and avoid using prime numbers.

Comment: I agree, I just wonder how much of a hit you would take using the pairs approach; especially memory-wise. Multiplying and even factoring an int is 'peanuts' for any modern CPU, looking up up a pair 2M times in a a dictionary is bound to have more overhead then doing the same with integers I'd guess. Then again, 2M loops is peanuts too nowadays. Only one way to be sure; maybe the OP might be willing to share his results? =)